# Installing readtext package

Tags: r, installation-package, stringi

I cannot install the readtext package, and I have tried two ways:

1. when trying 'install.packages (readtext)' a message is displayed saying that this is not available for R version 3.3.3
2. When trying to install it from github through devtools, it shows up the following message:

ERROR: dependency 'stringi' is not available for package 'readtext'
* removing [readtext from my library]
Error: Command failed (1)

This is weird because the stringr package is installed...

Thanks

Comment: `stringi` is not `stringr`

Comment: What is the output of this command `"stringi" %in% rownames(installed.packages())` ?

Comment: `readtext` is not in the CRAN repository (yet), so `install.packages()` wont work. What is the command you used with `devtools`? Which repository of CRAN are you using?

Comment: @MarcoSandri it is [1] TRUE

Comment: Are you using the following command for installation ?`devtools::install_github("kbenoit/readtext")`

Comment: Yes! It worked later on. but then it still didn't recognise some of the functions such as corpus...

Comment: As far as I can see the package `readtext` doesn't contain a function called `corpus`!